# UAC Disabled - "Run as administrator" still required on some programs?

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have Windows 7 SP1 x64, UAC is disabled, however some programs don't work unless I right click and do "Run as administrator" (or check the checkbox in properties of .exe file)
No UAC prompt shows either way, but these programs would give error messages or do nothing if started normally.

I've never experienced this before. Any ideas what could possibly cause this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes; UAC doesn't disable the need for Administrators; just the prompt

Comment: Yep, gets even more so on Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8.1... You will run as administrator or fail, and you will need to start the program as administrator, not hope for some silly prompt or auto-approve.

Answer (score -1):

UAC basically applies to two actions (although there may be more): changing Windows settings, and running programs that require "elevation" (administrator privileges).  At it's highest security level, UAC prompts you when you run a program that requires administrative privileges, or when Windows settings are changed.  *At it's lowest level, which is what you have it set to ("never notify"), it's not going to notify you of anything.*

Also, not all programs require elevation, for example, such as notepad because it doesn't need any "elevated" privileges (so it won't prompt you).  However, something such as "Disk Management", does require administrative privileges/elevation (and will).

And if you ever hear the term "elevated command prompt", it's just referring to a command prompt that you opened via "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Can't delete comment.

Comment: Noticed your comment before you deleted it.  Just a guess, but your answer doesn't do a good job of explaining what was asked in the question: why don't programs that require elevation run at this setting?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can't disagree... I just think I shouldn't get down-voted unless I was wrong or incorrect.  Also, the other answer doesn't answer why "programs don't work unless I right click and do Run as administrator'", either (not to be negative, just saying).